# Create a bookmark in shiny R app

Tags: r, shiny, bookmarks

I'm trying to implement a bookmark in a shiny R app.

I'm following this [example](https://gallery.shinyapps.io/113-bookmarking-url/?_inputs_&n=200) however, I get the following error:

```
Error in tag("div", list(...)) : could not find function "bookmarkButton"
```

I have searched this issue on web, but not found any help.

Can anyone help me on this issue?
Your help is much appreciated.
Best Regards.

Comment: You probably have to install the newest version of shiny because it looks like your current version doesn't have the function "bookmarkButton"

Comment: @MichalMajka Yes, you're right. Thank you